# creating a dropdown of available tables in a DB

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

This bit of code [below](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/list-table.php) connects to a DB(using [config.php](http://www.plus2net.com/php_tutorial/pdo-connection.php)) and then creates the below dropdown.

```
include "config.php"; // Database connection using PDO

//$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student"; 

$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student order by name"; 

/* You can add order by clause to the sql statement if the names are to be displayed in alphabetical order */

echo "<select name=student value=''>Student Name</option>"; // list box select command

foreach ($dbo->query($sql) as $row){//Array or records stored in $row

echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[name]</option>"; 

/* Option values are added by looping through the array */ 

}

 echo "</select>";// Closing of list box
```

This is the dropdown code that is created, and you can run it to see it in action.

```html
<br>
<br> The list box is here
<select name=student value=''>Student Name</option>
  <option value=1>John Deo</option>
  <option value=2>Max Ruin</option>
  <option value=3>Arnold</option>
  <option value=4>Krish Star</option>
  <option value=5>John Mike</option>
  <option value=6>Alex John</option>
  <option value=7>My John Rob</option>
  <option value=8>Asruid</option>
  <option value=9>Tes Qry</option>
  <option value=10>Big John</option>
  <option value=11>Ronald</option>
  <option value=12>Recky</option>
  <option value=13>Kty</option>
  <option value=14>Bigy</option>
  <option value=15>Tade Row</option>
  <option value=16>Gimmy</option>
  <option value=17>Tumyu</option>
  <option value=18>Honny</option>
  <option value=19>Tinny</option>
  <option value=20>Jackly</option>
  <option value=21>Babby John</option>
  <option value=22>Reggid</option>
  <option value=23>Herod</option>
  <option value=24>Tiddy Now</option>
  <option value=25>Giff Tow</option>
  <option value=26>Crelea</option>
  <option value=27>Big Nose</option>
  <option value=28>Rojj Base</option>
  <option value=29>Tess Played</option>
  <option value=30>Reppy Red</option>
  <option value=31>Marry Toeey</option>
  <option value=32>Binn Rott</option>
  <option value=33>Kenn Rein</option>
  <option value=34>Gain Toe</option>
  <option value=35>Rows Noump</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
```

what I want to do is change this line `$sql="SELECT name,id FROM student order by name";` so that the dropdown will contain all the tables in a DB for example `show tables`. **Given what I have provided can this be easily done?** Or should I use a different method? It would also be good if I could only show certain tables e.g. tables that begin with `Tab`.

like this

```html
<br>
<br> The list box is here with available tables
<select name=student value=''>TableName</option>
  <option value=1>Table1</option>
  <option value=2>Table2</option>
  <option value=3>Table3</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
```

**EDIT1** These are the lines I think I need to change; but this is my problem
`$sql="SHOW tables";`

`echo "<option value=$row[id]>$row[name]</option>";`

Comment: Have you tried to use 'show tables'?

Comment: @KIKO Software I have tried show tables but my prolem is in the php code to extract out what I want and put it in the html code. I should have specified this in the qestion.

Comment: It will work exactly the same as in the code you have. You will only get table names. In the `foreach` loop you can use `var_dump($row);`, instead of making the dropdown, to see what the result of the query is. That way you can find out what's in the row.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this and it worked using my server. The table_schema='yourDBname' is key because otherwise you can get dozens of random tables.

```
select table_name from information_schema.tables where table_schema='yourDBname'
```

You should be able to replace your query with this and do the same sort of drop down. Are you sure you want people to know the names of your tables though, for security reasons?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the table names from a specific schema using either `SHOW TABLES` as you suggested, or by selecting from [`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html), and you can filter by partial table names with either method.

```
$stmt = $dbo->query("SHOW TABLES FROM your_schema LIKE 'Tab%'");
```

or

```
$stmt = $dbo->query("SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
                     WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA='your_schema' AND TABLE_NAME LIKE 'Tab%'");
```

Either of these should give you the same result.

`$stmt` will be a `PDOStatement` object. You can use its [`fetchColumn`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php) method to get the table names as single values for your `<option>` values. This way, the odd "column name" generated by `SHOW TABLES` won't cause a problem if you decide to use that query.

```
echo '<select name="tables">';
while ($table_name = $stmt->fetchColumn()) {
    echo "<option value=\"$table_name\">$table_name</option>";
}
echo '</select>';
```